# Autohotkey Switch left and right mouse buttons

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

Im windows8 user, and Im trying to switch left and right buttom only inside Irfanview (picture viewer application) because the default pan always is left mouse buttom, but in irfan view is the right mouse buttom, So I want to whenever I hold down left mouse button, it send hold down right mouse buttom instead. I have tried this macro: it works inside Irfanview but also affect windows desktop, and sometimes some other programs also.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force
#Persistent
#InstallMouseHook

#ifWinActive ahk_class IrfanView
LButton::RButton
RButton::LButton

#IfWinActive ahk_class FullScreenClass
LButton::RButton
RButton::LButton
```

Could someone please give me some advice, pehaps is the conditional??

Thanks advanced.

Comment: Does this only happen when IrfanView is active and you click somewhere outside IrfanView's window, e.g. the Desktop beneath it? This is the only scenario in which I could reproduce this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is most likely due to the fact that one of your selected windows is activated, and you are trying to click on another window.

The solution to this would be to make your hotkeys use the window class the mouse is over instead of the active window.  I've included a function and how to use it below:

```
#If (MouseIsOverClass("IrfanView") or MouseIsOverClass("FullScreenClass")) and !MouseIsOverControl("IrfanViewerClass1")
    LButton::RButton
    RButton::LButton

MouseIsOverClass(WinClass) 
{
    MouseGetPos,,,win
    WinGetClass,class,ahk_id %win%
    return (class = winClass)
}

MouseIsOverControl(winControl)
{
    MouseGetPos, , , , Control
    return (Control = winControl)
}
```

EDIT: Note that `#If` is only supported in AHK_L.

[Documentation](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_If.htm)

Comment: I like this solution, very reusable, too. You could mention that `#If` is AHK_L only.

Comment: Thanks man, Just there is a little issue, if I open IrfanView I got to close its windows with the RMB, but I live with that, thanks.

Comment: You could probably resolve this using [MouseGetPos](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm) and add it to one of the `#If` conditions.  Please accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Hi Elliot, man please could you post the last line?, I am finding kinda anoing have to move IrfanView windows with the RMB, please man, What I got from the AutoIt3 Spy is... __                   ahk_class IrfanView (this is the main window, which I use to move IrfanView window and close it, I dont want to apply the LMB/RMB here).  __ ClassNN: IrfanViewerClass1 (whenever I put the mouse over a picture it appear this message, so I think here is where I want to apply the LMB/RMB change and also in FullScreenCLass)       Thanks Advanced man.

Comment: While it was not a single line, I added the exception when the mouse is over the `IrfanViewerClass1` control.

Comment: Could you post the script please Elliot DeNolf__?? How Do I add the exception to not apply the RMB/LMB switch when the cursor is over the ahk class IrfanView. And only apply it when the cursor is over the ClassNN IrfanViewClass1¿¿¿¿ Thanks Advanced.

Comment: ohh, I see, I replace the complete script with the new one you edited, but it does not work man. Now I got to pan inside irfanview with the RMB and I still got to close IrfanView windows with the RMB, did you use the ahk_class IrfanView. Thanks Advanced. please read What I get from Autolt3 Spy. THANKS ADVANCED.